# Monads in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, monads

So I want to understand the practical cases where monads in JavaScript are helpful.

I read a bunch on articles on Monads in JavaScript and understand that jQuery is one example of its use. But besides the "chaining" pattern, what other issues can be effectively solved using Monads in front-end engineering?

Ref:

http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/jquery-is-a-monad/

http://igstan.ro/posts/2011-05-02-understanding-monads-with-javascript.html

Comment: Monas — Scala monads for javascript
https://medium.com/@dmitrydoronin/monas-scala-monads-for-javascript-1e9cd7e82113

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I think the first article is great and quite detailed. It describes a lot of problems solved by JQuery and its monad nature.

1. JQuery wraps the DOM elements and gives a richer interface. The problems solved are numerous : richer events ("mouseenter","mouseleave","hashchnged" etc.. ). Event binding adds handlers instead of overriding. The interface for CSS handling is similar to other interfaces exposed by JQuery.

This is also the reason JQuery is so intuitive to a lot of developers as it simply wraps what we know and does not try to reinvent HTML.

Not to mention that it saves a lot of errors when referring to nulls. If I don't have an element with id `guy`, then running `$("#guy").text("I am not here")` will not cause an error in JQuery.

1. JQuery easily wraps itself around the DOM element allowing to traverse back and forward between raw JS and JQuery's interface. This allows developers to learn JQuery at their own pace instead of rewriting the entire code in one time.
2. When JQuery feeds a callback with arguments, it uses the DOM object instead of JQuery's wrapper. This allows 3rd-parties to easily integrate with JQuery as they don't need to rely on JQuery. 
   For example lets say I wrote a function that paints text in red using raw JavaScript. `function paintRed(element){element.style.color="red"}` - I can easily pass this function as callback to a JQuery function.

Comment: How does the Monad pattern lead to "richer events ("mouseenter","mouseleave","hashchnged" etc.. )" ?

Comment: Monad is not leading to richer events. You can have a Monad without it, and you can have richer events without a monad. however, wrapping the DOM is a monad quality. By supplying a  wrapper instead of a direct DOM access, you can enhance the behavior.

Answer (score 34):

Here is my attempt to contribute to monads-beginners that you probably never have found anywhere else.

### A monad is a highly composable unit (a kind of building block of programming) in functional programming.

(IMO, introducing "Monad laws" without any context and rationalization is merely a useless classification and hazard to understand the concept. No worry, I do the job later in this article.)

In most cases, we have many kinds of building blocks of programming such as object, function, list etc..

Although having varieties of blocks of programming seems law of nature and inevitable for flexible programming for practical purposes, the fact is having varieties of blocks is one of the major sources of programming environmental pollution.

Building blocks by using varieties of blocks is a complicated task. A programmer is required to select a block very wisely among varieties of blocks in every situation and in a long span, he will fail.

So, selecting varieties of blocks depends on situations is discouraged, instead, it is a good discipline always to use a certain pre-selected block that is universally standardized.

In fact, this wisdom is common in PC-world in these days.

> [USB, short for Universal Serial Bus, is an industry standard that was developed to define cables, connectors and protocols for connection, communication, and power supply between personal computers and their peripheral devices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)

Obtaining a well-designed universally standardized building block eliminate many problems.

1. [Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) is (used to be) the one.
2. [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) is the one.
3. [Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) is the one.
4. Specifications
5. Implementation
6. Verification

## 1.OOP

> [Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of "objects", which may contain data, in the form of fields, often known as attributes; and code, in the form of procedures, often known as methods. A feature of objects is that an object's procedures can access and often modify the data fields of the object with which they are associated (objects have a notion of "this" or "self"). In OOP, computer programs are designed by making them out of objects that interact with one another. There is significant diversity of OOP languages, but the most popular ones are class-based, meaning that objects are instances of classes, which typically also determine their type.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science))

Selecting object as a universally standardized building block, a programmer prepares a base class that contains member values and functions, and in order to obtain variations of the blocks, [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) is used.

OOP idea is often explained by using real-world physical objects, and the paradigm itself is weak on mathematical abstraction.

For instance, functions(or methods) are subordinate to objects, and functions are not required to be a [first-class object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), and this is as a matter of course since the paradigm originally selected object as their well-designed universally standardized building block.

The perspective of where functions are subordinate entities to objects as the standardized building block and both roles are strictly different comes from an engineering sense in the physical world. not the mathematical abstraction where programming actually resides.

The fundamental problem of OOP is simply that object turns out to be not the well-designed universally standardized building block. Functional programming or monad are the better alternatives with the strong mathematical background.

## 2.Functional Programming

**Functional programming is all about composing functions.**

Saying that is easy, but this is quite an achievement of the history of programming.

Instead of studying the long history of programming, I'd like to share my personal history.

I used to be a C#(OOP)programmer since version1.0, and overall I had been satisfied but felt something very wrong, but did not know what it was.

I later became a JavaScript programmer, and in the early days, I used to write like this:

```js
function add1(a) {
    return a + 1;
}
```

One day, I read some web article saying "In JavaScript, a function is also a value."

The fact is quite surprising to me and break-through to my programming skill.

Until then, to me, it's so obvious that value is value, and a function is a function; both are absolutely different entities in different realms.

Of course, C#1.0 already implemented delegate and I slightly understand it's something about the internal mechanism of events. After all, C# has been a major OOP language and quite ugly for functional programming, at least in version1.0.

In JavaScript, a function is also a value. Since functions of JavaScript is a first-class object, I can define a function that can either take other functions as arguments or return them as results.

So, now, I write this:

```js
const add1 = x => x + 1;
const add2 = x => x + 2;
[1, 2, 3].map(add1); //[2,3,4]
[1, 2, 3].map(add2); //[3,4,5]
```

or

```js
const plus = (x) => (y => x + y);
plus(1)(5); //6
```

In fact, this is what I badly needed in C# programming, that has been something very wrong I felt about.

This is called [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), and this is the true secret to release the constraints of programming.

So, a function of JavaScript is a first-class object, and it seems to be a well-designed universally standardized building block, well from now on, let's call it "highly composable units".

A Function is `BEFORE => AFTER`.

The basic idea is to compose functions.

When you focus on functional composition, you only care various compositions of `BEFORE => AFTER`.

When you focus on functional composition, you should forget [flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) that　flows from the top to the bottom of the code or sometimes loops.

Flowchart coding is called [Imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), and generally speaking, it's buggy and too complicated. OOP tends to become this style.

On the other hand, functional programming automatically leads programming style to [Declarative_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), and generally speaking, it's not buggy or easy to debug.

Flows are harder to trace and control, but compositions are rather easier to trace and control. Programmers should not control flows but compose functions.

## 3.Monad

By the way, I will not use Haskell code here.

For most of the people, a major obstacle to understanding monad things is

1. In order to learn monad, a beginner needs to be comfortable with Haskell code and terms.
2. In order to be comfortable with Haskell code and terms, a beginner needs to learn Monad.

This is "Which came first, the chicken or the egg?" problem. Make sure to avoid.

Having said that, as I stated at the beginning of this article, to share knowledge of Monad, quoting "Monad laws" first also seems absurd.

People only can learn based on top of what they already knew.

So, let's back to JavaScript code.

Functions appear to be highly composable units, but what about this?

```js
console.log("Hello world!");
```

This is one of the simplest JS code, and surely it's a function.

Hit F12-key on ChromeBrowser, and copy-paste the code on the developer-console.

```
Hello world!
undefined
```

Ok, the code has done the task to show "Hello world!" on the console, however, the return value of the `console.log` function is `undefined`.

To compose functions, the situation is uncomfortable; an uncomfortable function.

On the other hand, there's a comfortable function.　Let's investigate the following code:

```js
const add1 = x => x + 1;
[1, 2, 3].map(add1); //[2,3,4]
```

Array in JavaScript behaves pretty well in the functional programming world.

```js
[1, 2, 3].map(add1)   //[2,3,4]
```

indicates:
`Array` `Function=>` `Array`

Input and Output of the function is the same type: `Array`.

The mathematical structure is identical throughout `BEFORE => AFTER`.

The nature of consistency and identity is beautiful.

The intriguing similarity to USB interface naturally leads an idea:
`Array` `Function=>` `Array` `Function=>` `Array` `Function=>` `Array`...

In JavaScript code:

```js
[1, 2, 3]
  .map(add1) //[2,3,4]
  .map(add1) //[3,4,5]
  .map(add1);//[4,5,6]
```

The code suggests once you enter Array realm, the exit will be always Array realm, so there's no exit in a sense.

Since Array realm is a world of self-contained, it is possible to do something like algebra in functional programming.

When we have:

```js
Array.map(F).map(F).map(F)...
```

Considering `.map(F)` is JavaScript Array specific syntax, replacing it to more concise syntax would be possible, for instance, by taking advantage of some transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

So replacing `.map(F)` to `*F`:

```js
Array*F*F*F...
```

This looks like [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra).

Obtaining highly composable units, a programmer can write a code like algebra, which means significant, and worth studying very seriously.

In algebra,

```
a
= 0+a
= 0+0+a
= 0+0+0+a
```

or

```
a
= 1*a
= 1*1*a
= 1*1*1*a
```

`0` in +(addition) operation,

```
a + 0 = a  //right identity
0 + a = a  //left identity
```

`1` in *(multiplication) operation,

```
a ∗ 1 = a  //right identity
1 ∗ a = a  //left identity
```

is called [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

In algebra,

```
1 + 2 + 3 = 1 + 2 + 3
(1+2) + 3 = 1 + (2+3)
    3 + 3 = 1 + 5
        6 = 6
```

is called [associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)

```
number + number = number

number * number = number

string + string = string

"Hello" + " " + "world" + "!" 
= "Hello world" + "!" 
= "Hello "+ "world!"
```

is also associative, and identity element is `""`.

So, what is the identity element in functional programming?

Something like:

```
identityF * f = f = f * identityF
```

What is it like associative property in functional programming?

```
const add1 = x => x + 1;
const add2 = x => x + 2;
const add3 = x => x + 2;
```

Something like:

```
add1 * add2 * add3
= (add1 * add2) * add3
= add1 * (add2 * add3)
```

or

```
 　(add1)(add2)(add3) = (add1)(add2)(add3)
 ((add1)(add2))(add3) = (add1)((add2)(add3))
         (add3)(add3) = (add1)(add5)
　             (add6) = (add6)
```

Functional programming is all about function composition.

What we need in functional programming is

```
function * function = function
```

Of course, in JavaScript(or in other languages), we cannot write the exact form above because of the restrictions of the syntax of every language.

In fact, we can have ["Algebraic JavaScript Specification"(Specification for interoperability of common algebraic structures in JavaScript)](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land)

[image: Algebraic JavaScript Specification]

So is JavaScript array so-called Monad?

No, but close. JavaScript array can be classified as [Functor](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor).

[Monad](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad) is a special form of Functor, with some extra natures (more rules applied).

Functor is still one of the highly composable units.

So we are getting close to what Monad is. Let's go further.

Now, we know JavaScript array is one of the highly composable units that can do some algebra, at least to a certain extent.

So what about JavaScript values other than arrays? what about functions?

Studying and following [Algebraic JavaScript Specification](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land), it would be easy to attempt to implement various composable units, including Functor or Monad, what is the point?

After all, they are merely classification table for Mathematics structure, and following the specification blindly does not make sense.

## 4.Specification

The point is to obtain a highly composable unit that realm is self-contained. This is the only specification to be satisfied.

So, here's the problem establishment:
Implement a Math structure that generates a self-contained realm, and see how it goes.

Anything is fine, and I will start from scratch, but I already have a good model to refer.

JavaScript Array

```
Array.map(F).map(F).map(F)...
```

Instead of the Array realm, let's make my original `M` realm like this:

```
M.map(F).map(F).map(F)...
```

I think `Array.map` is not a concise syntax, `M` itself is a function:

```
M(F)(F)(F)...
```

Well, it is a good discipline always to use a certain pre-selected block that is universally standardized. That is the idea to start, so probably,`F` also should be `M` :

```
M(M)(M)(M)...
```

Hmm, what does this mean??

So, here's my crazy idea.

In functional programming, any functions are also first-class object, and that is the break-through. So when I interpret any value/object/function as `M`, there will be another break-through.

This is crazy like saying "Any values are Array!".

To be exact, it is crazy if it's in the realm of JavaScript, but it is legitimate if it's in the self-contained realm of Array.

So, I will design that the original `M` realm will treat any naked  value/object/function as `M`

For instance, in the `M` realm, when naked value:`5` is found, interpreted as `M(5)`.

In other words, as long as in the `M` realm, a programmer does not have to write `M(5)` since `5` is implicitly interpreted as `M(5)`.

Accordingly, in the `M` realm:

```
5
= M(5)
= M(M(5))
= M(M(M(5)))
...
```

As a result, I found `M` is somewhat transparent and, `M` should be an identity element in the realm.

As I have been emphasizing, **Functional programming is all about composing functions.**

Composition of function is associative for functional programming.

The `M` should be flexibly written to compose functions:

```js
const add1 = x => x + 1;
M(10)(add1);             //11
M(10)(add1)(add1);       //12
M(10)(add1)(add1)(add1); //13
const add2 = M(add1)(add1);
M(10)(add2);             //12
const add3 = M(add2)(add1);   
M(10)(add3);             //13
```

Also, composition of higher-order functions:

```js
const plus = (x) => (y => x + y);
M(plus(1)(5));    //6
M(5)(M(1)(plus)); //6
const plus1 = M(1)(plus);
M(5)(plus1);     //6
```

## 5.Implementation

Here's an implementation of `M`:

```js
const compose = (f, g) => (x => g(f(x)));
const isMonad = (m) => !(typeof m.val === "undefined");

const M = (m = []) => {
  const f = m1 => {
    try { //check type error
      return M(M(m1).val(m));
    } catch (e) {
      return M(compose(m, M(m1).val)); // f-f compose
    };
  };
  f.val = m;
  return isMonad(m)
    ? m
    : f;
};
M.val = m => m;
```

Logging function:

```js
const log = (m) => (typeof m !== 'function')
  ? (() => {
    console.log(m);
    return m;
  })()
  : err();
```

Test code:

```js
const err = () => {
  throw new TypeError();
};

const log = (m) => (typeof m !== 'function')
  ? (() => {
    console.log(m);
    return m;
  })()
  : err();

const loglog = M(log)(log);
M("test")(loglog);

M("------")(log);
M([1])(log);
M(M(M(5)))(log)
M(99)(M)(log)

M("------")(log);
M([1, 2, 3])(([a, b, c]) => [a + 1, b + 1, c + 1])(log)

M("------")(log);

const add1 = a => (typeof a == 'number')
  ? a + 1
  : err();

M(10)(add1)(log); //11
M(10)(add1)(add1)(log); //12
M(10)(add1)(add1)(add1)(log); //13
const add2 = M(add1)(add1);
M(10)(add2)(log); //12
const add3 = M(add2)(add1);
M(10)(add3)(log); //13

M("------")(log);
const plus = (x) => (y => x + y);
M(plus(1)(5))(log); //6
M(5)(M(1)(plus))(log); //6
const plus1 = M(1)(plus);
M(5)(plus1)(log); //6

M("------")(log);
const map = (f) => (array => array.map(f));
const map1 = M(add1)(map);
M([1, 2, 3])(log)(map1)(log);

//===

M("left identity   M(a)(f) = f(a)")(log);
M(7)(add1)(log) //8

M("right identity  M = M(M)")(log);
console.log(M) //{ [Function: M] val: [Function] }
console.log(M(M)) //{ [Function: M] val: [Function] }

M("identity")(log);
M(9)(M(x => x))(log); //9
M(9)(x => x)(log); //9

M("homomorphism")(log);
M(100)(M(add1))(log); //101
M(add1(100))(log); //101

M("interchange")(log);
M(3)(add1)(log); //4
M(add1)(f => f(3))(log); //4

M("associativity")(log);
M(10)(add1)(add1)(log); //12
M(10)(M(add1)(add1))(log); //12
```

Output:

```
test
test
------
[ 1 ]
5
99
------
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
------
11
12
13
12
13
------
6
6
6
------
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
left identity   M(a)(f) = f(a)
8
right identity  M = M(M)
{ [Function: M] val: [Function] }
{ [Function: M] val: [Function] }
identity
9
9
homomorphism
101
101
interchange
4
4
associativity
12
12
```

Ok, worked.

`M` is a highly composable unit in functional programming.

## 6.Verification

So, is this so-called Monad?

Yes.

https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad

> #### Monad
>
> A value that implements the Monad specification must also implement
> the [Applicative](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#applicative) and [Chain](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain) specifications.
>
> 1. `M.of(a).chain(f)` is equivalent to `f(a)` (left identity)
> 2. `m.chain(M.of)` is equivalent to `m` (right identity)

##### left identity   M(a)(f) = f(a)

```js
M(7)(add1) //8
M(add1(7)) //8
```

##### right identity  M = M(M)

```js
console.log(M) //{ [Function: M] val: [Function] }
console.log(M(M)) //{ [Function: M] val: [Function] }
```

> #### Applicative
>
> A value that implements the Applicative specification must also
> implement the [Apply](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) specification.
>
> 1. `v.ap(A.of(x => x))` is equivalent to `v` (identity)
> 2. `A.of(x).ap(A.of(f))` is equivalent to `A.of(f(x))` (homomorphism)
> 3. `A.of(y).ap(u)` is equivalent to `u.ap(A.of(f => f(y)))` (interchange)

##### identity

```js
M(9)(M(x => x)) //9
```

##### homomorphism

```js
M(100)(M(add1)) //101
M(add1(100)) //101
```

##### interchange

```js
M(3)(add1)    //4
M(add1)(f => f(3))  //4
```

> #### Chain
>
> A value that implements the Chain specification must also
> implement the [Apply](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) specification.
>
> 1. `m.chain(f).chain(g)` is equivalent to `m.chain(x => f(x).chain(g))` (associativity)

##### associativity

```js
M(10)(add1)(add1) //12
M(10)(M(add1)(add1)) //12
```

Comment: Monas — Scala monads for javascript
https://medium.com/@dmitrydoronin/monas-scala-monads-for-javascript-1e9cd7e82113

Comment: Great post thanks! Slightly disappointed that you've had to use mutations over functions in your monad implementation, which makes it IMHO harder to read and not so aligned with the functional programming philosophy. Couldn't this be done with more explicit objects like `{val, function}`?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid using global variables and state when using monads (e.g. "pure" code). You might also want to take a look at https://github.com/brownplt/flapjax/. Flapjax is a function reactive programming library which also using a monadic approach.

Comment: There's also [Bacon.js](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js), which seems to be a bit more extensive and actively under development. The docs are good also.

Answer (score 1):

Passing arguments to a given callback function within a particular scope can be generalized using a monad:

```
/* Unit function */
function Monad(value)
  {
  // Construct monad and set value to given argument or undefined
  this.value = value || undefined;
  }

/* Constructor function */
Monad.prototype.pass = function(value, cb, scope)
  {
  // return constructor result if no default value is passed
  if (/undefined/.test(this.value) )
    {
    return new this.constructor();
    }
  // return callback result for given value in given context if scope is passed
  if(scope)
    {
    /* Bind function */
    return cb.call(scope, value);
    }
  // return callback result for given value otherwise
  return cb(value);
  }

 /* Separate arguments from function, and function from global scope */
 var foo = new Monad(RegExp);
 var bar = foo.pass(2, Function("count","return ++count"), Math);
```

**References**

- [On Monads](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/wiki?OnMonads)
- [Transparent Persistence](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/526)
- [Monad-Dyad](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310v.htm)
- [Common Logic Controlled English](http://www.jfsowa.com/clce/specs.htm)
- [The JSON Parser Monad - Parsing JSON the fun way (Part 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fzandona/archive/2011/11/02/parsing-json-the-fun-way-json-parser-monad-part-3.aspx)
- [Fortran 77 Semantic Analysis](http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/fortran_html/Semantics.html)
- [Practical Monads](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Practical_monads)
- [A Poor Man's Concurrency Monad](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis552/11fa/lectures/concurrency.html)

Comment: It is not very clear how this example is a Monad. Could you expand on a) it's monadic nature (possibly relating to the three monadic laws) and b) an usage example for this and how it improves the comprehension of your typical code? Thanks.

Comment: @Sukima I've added comments and a usage example.